# How to better understand where the circles and lines go under fractional linear transformations?

Tags: complex-analysis, special-functions, rational-functions

Today I encountered the transformation $f(z) = \frac{z}{z-1}$. It has the following property:

- As the point $z$ makes a counter-clockwise revolution around the unit circle beginning at $1$, the point $f(z)$ parametrizes the line with real part $1/2$, travelling upward.

This is not a difficult thing to verify with a bit of fiddling around. I used this fact to show that a certain operator had a gap in its spectrum. But, if I hadn't already expected this was going to happen for another reason, I would never have noticed the above property of this transformation.

Another example: the Cayley transform $f(z) = \frac{z -i}{z+i}$.

- As $z$ travels the real line from left to right, $f(z)$ undergoes a counterclockwise revolution of the circle, beginning and ending at $1$.

Again, this is easy to check. I'm aware of the phenomenon because the transform is relatively famous, but, if I had encountered this transformation "in the wild", I would never have expected the above property.  Which leads to my question:

> Is there some more systematic way to see where lines and circles go under fractional linear transformations $f(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$? I can verify expected facts by doing things like computing the norm, or real and imaginary parts of the right hand side, but I cannot help but feel like there is some gap in my knowledge that prevents me from really *understanding* what is going on.

Comment: If a circle is mapped to a line, note that the circle must contain $-d/c$ so that the point at infinity is attained. Conversely if a line is mapped to a circle then $a/c$ will be on the circle for similar reasons.

Comment: @alex: Ahhh OK so, with $f(z) = \frac{z}{z-1}$, the unit circle must go to either a circle or a line and, since $f(1) = \infty$, it goes to a line. Then it's just a matter of seeing where, e.g., $i$ and $-1$ go to see which line, and deduce the direction of the parametrization?

Comment: @alex: did you mean "$a/c$ will be on the line" in your last sentence above?

Comment: It's not clear a priori that for $z\mapsto\frac{z}{z-1}$ that the unit circle would have to be mapped to a circle or a line; but if it _were_ mapped to a line, that line contains the point at infinity in the compactification of $\mathbb{R}^2$. And the preimage of that point at infinity is $-d/c$. To the second question, I think I did mean as it is stated. When you "plug in" the point at infinity into a fractional linear transformation, the output is $a/c$. So if a line is to wind up being mapped to a circle, $a/c$ would be on that circle.

Comment: @alex: OK I see that makes sense. But I guess, to deduce that a line $L$ is to be sent to a circle, the thing to check would be that $-d/c \notin L$ so that everywhere on $L$ is sent somewhere finite. So, for example, $-i \notin \mathbb{R}$ for the Cayley transform.

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_transformation#Preservation_of_angles_and_generalized_circles).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$\frac{az+b}{cz+d} = \frac{a}{c} + \frac{bc-ad}{c}\frac{1}{cz+d} \tag1$$
every Möbius map is a composition of linear maps and $z\mapsto z^{-1}$. Linear maps are simple enough: lines clearly go to lines and circles to circles  (with center of circle mapped to the center of the new circle). It remains to figure out the map $z\mapsto z^{-1}$. Geometrically it is easier to work with inversion map $z\mapsto \bar z^{-1}$ and compose it with conjugation (in either order). The reason is that in polar coordinates $z\mapsto \bar z^{-1}$ is written as $$re^{i\theta}\to r^{-1}e^{i\theta}\tag2$$ That is, the polar angle remains but the distance to the origin is inverted.

Inversion of a circle centered at $0$ is another circle centered at $0$. Inversion of a circle centered at $a\ne 0$ can be computed by focusing on the line $L$ through $0$ and $a$. Let $p$ and $q$ be the points where $L$  crosses the circle. Their images will be on the same line. Most importantly, the image of the circle will still be symmetric about $L$, since (2) preserves such symmetry. Thus, $\bar p^{-1}$ and $\bar q^{-1}$ are endpoints of a diameter. Thus the image circle has diameter $|p^{-1}-q^{-1}|$ and center $\frac12(\bar p^{-1}+\bar q^{-1})$. That is, ...

unless one of $p$ and $q$ is $0$; say $p=0$. Then we get a line passing through $\bar q^{-1}$. Since it's symmetric about $L$, it must be perpendicular to $L$. This determines the line.

Comment: Thanks. I think as it turns out the thing I was not noticing was just "if the circle $C$ contains $-d/c$, then $z \mapsto \frac{az + b}{cz +d}$ maps $C$ to a line" and the corresponding condition detecting when a line is mapped to a bounded circle. But it is nice to have the justification for the whole circles & lines $\to$ circles & lines story here.